# Android SDK support

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools

I am new to android and i have a doubt that if we remove Android SDK from Android Studio and install Android NDK in it, than in this situation Android Studio will work or not. Or can we create apps in java in this situation.(I think we can't).

Answer (score 1):

REFER the link given below...

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html